# Vaadin blocks Swagger-UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, vaadin, openapi, vaadin-flow

Iam trying to get swagger to work besides my Vaadin-Flow Application.
Iam currently using Vaadin 22.0.4 with Spring-Boot 2.6.3 and springdoc-openapi-ui 1.6.5.
The Swagger-ui should be available under `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui`, but it is not:

[image]

I guess it gets blocked by vaadin in some way.
Things like `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs` or Rest-Endpoints created by spring work fine.

Is there a way to allow a specific routes for swagger to work?

What i tried so far:

1. Using spring security to allow swagger (extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and overriting `configure`). There is a example of one try in the repository linked below.
2. Using `vaadin.urlMapping=/foo/*` in the application.properties to change the root mapping from vaadin. That kinda works... Swagger is available under `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui` and the Vaadin UI under `http://localhost:8080/foo`. I am just looking for the other way around. Vaadin should be available under `http://localhost:8080/`. But that shows that swagger would work.
3. Using Swagger 2
4. springdoc.swagger-ui.path

I also Uploaded a plain Vaadin project where the issue is reproducible:
https://github.com/DerAzubi/swagger-test
(to test the application just start the main function)

the last commit contains all changes made to the default vaadin starter.

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/10163

Comment: @TatuLund thanks for the answer. Does not look like its the same Problem. When i Map Vaadin to `/ui/*` then swagger will start fine. In the linked issue it does not start and fails with an js error (i could reproduce that with vaadin 14 for example, but iam using 22.0.4). Any other idea for a workaround/fix?

Comment: What's happens here is most likely related to mapping priorities with handlers registered through Spring's dispatcher servlet. You probably need to find a way of increasing the priority of the Swagger handler so that it is given a chance to handle specific requests before Vaadin handles them.

Comment: I've never managed to have Swagger and also Camunda run with Vaadin on root path.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli so you have Vaadin Running under /ui/* (or something else)?

Comment: As far as I know, there is currently no way (or easy way at least) to get Swagger to work without changing Vaadin's URL mapping. I opened a ticket to enable that though: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/12949.

Comment: Yes exactly. I set the url

Comment: @TarekOraby thanks alot. Looking forward for a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Vaadin 23.3.0 but not in a fully automatic way. You can define paths to exclude, e.g. `vaadin.excludeUrls=/swagger-ui/**` and those will not be handled by the Vaadin servlet when it is mapped to /*